# Define derived type array

Tags: arrays, fortran, derived-types

I am trying to initialize a derived type using a parameter declaration. When I compile, I get the following error

> Element in INTEGER(4) array constructor at (1) is CHARACTER(1).

User defined kinds values `ip` and `dp` are found in `fasst_global`. They are:

```
integer,parameter:: ip = selected_int_kind(8)
integer,parameter:: dp = selected_real_kind(15,307)
```

I have tried using `1_ip` instead of `1` as the first element and it made no difference. What am I doing wrong?

```
module fasst_derived_types
  use fasst_global

  implicit none

  type fasst_default_soil
    integer(ip):: sid
    character(len=2):: ssname
    real(dp):: dens,pors,ssemis,ssalb,shc,smin,smax,salpha,svgn
    real(dp):: sspheat,sorgan,spsand,spsilt,spclay,spgravel
  end type fasst_default_soil

  type(fasst_default_soil),parameter:: fasst_soil(1) = fasst_default_soil( &

    (/1, 'GW',1.947_dp,0.293_dp, 0.92_dp,0.40_dp,1.1197e-2_dp,        &
             0.01_dp,0.293_dp,22.6125_dp, 3.45_dp,  820.0_dp,       &
              0.0_dp,  5.0_dp, 2.0_dp, 2.0_dp,91.0_dp/))

end module fasst_derived_types
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use two constructors here:

- an array constructor;
- a structure constructor.

You have the correct syntax for each, but you are using them incorrectly.

The array constructor `(/.../)` is to construct an array.  But you want an array of derived type values (well, one value) rather than an array as the component for a single derived type value.  The syntax error comes from attempting to create an array with various different/incompatible types.

So, instead you want

```
type(fasst_default_soil),parameter:: fasst_soil(1) = (/fasst_default_soil(1_ip,'GW', ...)/)
```

Or, as you just want a single element array you don't even need to construct that array of derived types.

Comment: The array is actually of size 30, but I decrease to dimension 1 to debug. I have it now, thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2417662 You don't have to thank in the comments, but you should mark the answer that helped you as accepted.