# defining default values for an array of derived data type

Tags: fortran, derived-types

In fortran you can define a default value for a variable on declaration which can be overwritten later in the code, also giving default values for all entries in an derived type array as follows:

```
PROGRAM test
TYPE data
  INTEGER :: j=0
  CHARACTER(len=10)::label="hello"
END TYPE data
TYPE(data) :: obj(2)

! overwrite the default of 0 in the first array entry
obj(1)%j=6  ! etc etc

END PROGRAM test
```

all very straightforward. But what is the syntax used for defining a default set of values for all array entries of derived datatypes?  I looked up a few tutorials, but none of them addressed this.  In other words, to have `j=0` in the first element of `obj%j` by default and set it to 1 in the second and so on...

```
PROGRAM test

TYPE data
  INTEGER :: j
  CHARACTER(len=10)::label
END TYPE data

TYPE(data) :: obj(2)=??? ! what do I put to define an array of default types?

! for example these might be my desired default values
obj(1)%j=0
obj(1)%label="bad"
obj(2)%j=1
obj(2)%label="good"

END PROGRAM test
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First a note on terminology: in a statement like

```
integer, save :: i=1
```

this doesn't provide a "default" value for `i`, it provides an *initial* value for i. We call this *explicit initialization*. (Note how I've put the SAVE attribute there just to make it obvious; the attribute is implicit.)

The syntax for such explicit initialization is the same whether the object is of intrinsic or derived type, a scalar or an array:

```
type(decl_type), save[, attributes] :: myobj = initial_expression
```

where `decl_type` is `integer`, `real`, `my_type`, etc.  (`type(integer)` can of course be written as the simple `integer`.)

For derived type, we just need to find a suitable initialization expression.

For an array `myobj` this expression can be a scalar (in which case all elements of the array initially have that value), or an array.  Obvious cases use the default structure constructor:

```
type(my_type), save               :: myobj1 = decl_type(comps)
type(my_type), save, dimension(2) :: myobj2 = decl_type(comps)
type(my_type), save, dimension(2) :: myobj3 = [decl_type(comps1), decl_type(comps2)]
```

If you want to construct an array using the structure constructor, note that you need an array constructor: the structure constructor [isn't elemental](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34402630/3157076).

More generally we can use things other than the default structure constructor, but the expression must be a *constant expression*.

To provide an example suiting the question:

```
implicit none

type data
  integer :: j
  character(10) :: label
end type data

type(data), save, dimension(2) :: mydata=[data(0,"bad"), data(1,"good")]

end
```

Finally, if the derived type has *default initialization* for components, they can be omitted from the structure constructor:

```
implicit none

type data
  integer :: j=-1
  character(10) :: label="nothing"
end type data

type(data), save, dimension(2) :: mydata=data()

end
```

Comment: Beautiful answer. Thank you